# Magento 2.3.7 new installation not show error and none log, but use blank page without styles

Tags: magento2.3, css, symlinks

recently installed magento 2.3.7 via composer, but not get any error from log or browser, this is my apache configuration , luma not working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias magento.test
ServerAdmin webmaster@demo.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/Magento/Test/mage/pub"
ServerName magento.test
<Directory "/Users/Magento/Test/mage/">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/magento_error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/magento_access_log" common
```

And I have all .htaccess in root, pub, static , and my magento url path is set as

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://magento.test/"
```

I try it

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

So try it

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

And

```
grunt clean
grunt exec
grunt less --force
```

Aditional all permissions for directories

So try it

```
    <virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And try in /pub/static/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

<FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$>
    Header append Cache-Control public
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
    Header append Cache-Control no-store
</FilesMatch>
```

from my original so not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
#RewriteBase /magento/pub/static/
RewriteEngine /pub/static/

# Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
# Detects if moxieplayer request with uri params and redirects to uri without params
<Files moxieplayer.swf>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
 </Files>
```

[image]

Comment: rewrite mode is enabled ? if not you can do with: sudo a2enmod rewrite
And restart apache.

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies yes, is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigate , set pcre.jit=0 solve this

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with magento 2.4.4, how can I fix it. I don't know in which file to modify set pcre.jit=0

[image]